# Mongo count php from collections by element

Tags: php, mongodb, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am new to mongo queries I have a lot of collections look like this:

```
{
"_id" : "a6136d1a-d676-4352-8d54-d51645edfe84",
"className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.HistoricHand",
"table" : {
    "tableId" : 5,
    "tableIntegrationId" : "TABLE::eb54b0e9-693c-4f4b-8d3a-a62edfc9e9ac",
    "tableName" : "Orem",
    "seats" : 0
},
"startTime" : NumberLong(1447486395510),
"endTime" : NumberLong(1447486423769),
"deckInfo" : {
    "size" : 52,
    "lowRank" : "TWO"
},
"results" : {
    "totalRake" : "2.80",
    "results" : {
        "85" : {
            "playerId" : 85,
            "netWin" : "217.20",
            "totalWin" : "277.20",
            "rake" : "0.60",
            "totalBet" : "60.00",
            "transactionId" : "275"
        },
        "19" : {
            "playerId" : 19,
            "netWin" : "-20.00",
            "totalWin" : "0.00",
            "rake" : "0.20",
            "totalBet" : "20.00",
            "transactionId" : "275"
        },
        "71" : {
            "playerId" : 71,
            "netWin" : "-60.00",
            "totalWin" : "0.00",
            "rake" : "0.60",
            "totalBet" : "60.00",
            "transactionId" : "275"
        },
        "82" : {
            "playerId" : 82,
            "netWin" : "-20.00",
            "totalWin" : "0.00",
            "rake" : "0.20",
            "totalBet" : "20.00",
            "transactionId" : "275"
        },
        "8" : {
            "playerId" : 8,
            "netWin" : "-20.00",
            "totalWin" : "0.00",
            "rake" : "0.20",
            "totalBet" : "20.00",
            "transactionId" : "275"
        },
        "92" : {
            "playerId" : 92,
            "netWin" : "-20.00",
            "totalWin" : "0.00",
            "rake" : "0.20",
            "totalBet" : "20.00",
            "transactionId" : "275"
        },
        "26" : {
            "playerId" : 26,
            "netWin" : "-20.00",
            "totalWin" : "0.00",
            "rake" : "0.20",
            "totalBet" : "20.00",
            "transactionId" : "275"
        },
        "62" : {
            "playerId" : 62,
            "netWin" : "-60.00",
            "totalWin" : "0.00",
            "rake" : "0.60",
            "totalBet" : "60.00",
            "transactionId" : "275"
        }
    }
},
"events" : [ 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "ANTE",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "20.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 19,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396526)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "ANTE",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "20.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 92,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396528)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "ANTE",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "20.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 8,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396530)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "ANTE",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "20.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 62,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396532)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "ANTE",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "20.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 85,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396534)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "ANTE",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "20.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 26,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396536)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "ANTE",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "20.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 71,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396538)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "ANTE",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "20.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 82,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396540)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PotUpdate",
        "pots" : [ 
            {
                "potId" : 0,
                "players" : [ 
                    85, 
                    19, 
                    71, 
                    82, 
                    8, 
                    92, 
                    26, 
                    62
                ],
                "potSize" : "160.00"
            }
        ],
        "type" : "PotUpdate",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396541)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 19,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "DIAMONDS",
                "rank" : "FIVE"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : false,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396542)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 62,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "CLUBS",
                "rank" : "KING"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : false,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396542)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 92,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "SPADES",
                "rank" : "TWO"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : false,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396542)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 8,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "SPADES",
                "rank" : "QUEEN"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : false,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396542)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 85,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "CLUBS",
                "rank" : "FIVE"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : false,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396542)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 26,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "SPADES",
                "rank" : "THREE"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : false,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396542)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 71,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "DIAMONDS",
                "rank" : "NINE"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : false,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396542)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 82,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "CLUBS",
                "rank" : "SIX"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : false,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396542)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 19,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "SPADES",
                "rank" : "NINE"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : true,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396543)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 62,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "HEARTS",
                "rank" : "QUEEN"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : true,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396543)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 92,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "HEARTS",
                "rank" : "SIX"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : true,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396543)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 8,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "SPADES",
                "rank" : "SEVEN"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : true,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396543)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 85,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "HEARTS",
                "rank" : "FIVE"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : true,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396543)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 26,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "CLUBS",
                "rank" : "TEN"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : true,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396543)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 71,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "DIAMONDS",
                "rank" : "KING"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : true,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396543)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerCardsDealt",
        "playerId" : 82,
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "suit" : "HEARTS",
                "rank" : "SEVEN"
            }
        ],
        "isExposed" : true,
        "type" : "PlayerCardsDealt",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486396543)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.RoundStarted",
        "type" : "RoundStarted",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486397546)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "BET",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "40.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 71,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486398549)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "FOLD",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "0.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 82,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486399554)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "FOLD",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "0.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 19,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486401734)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "CALL",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "40.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 62,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486404775)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "FOLD",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "0.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 92,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486409799)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "FOLD",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "0.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 8,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486412019)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "RAISE",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "80.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 85,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486416126)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "FOLD",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "0.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 26,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486419487)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "FOLD",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "0.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 71,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486421934)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PlayerAction",
        "action" : "FOLD",
        "amount" : {
            "type" : "BET",
            "amount" : "0.00"
        },
        "timeout" : false,
        "playerId" : 62,
        "type" : "PlayerAction",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486423531)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.PotUpdate",
        "pots" : [ 
            {
                "potId" : 0,
                "players" : [ 
                    85, 
                    19, 
                    71, 
                    82, 
                    8, 
                    92, 
                    26, 
                    62
                ],
                "potSize" : "280.00"
            }
        ],
        "type" : "PotUpdate",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486423532)
    }, 
    {
        "className" : "com.cubeia.poker.handhistory.api.ShowDownSummary",
        "type" : "ShowDownSummary",
        "time" : NumberLong(1447486423769)
    }
],
"seats" : [ 
    {
        "playerId" : 19,
        "initialBalance" : "2000.00",
        "seatId" : 0,
        "name" : "Bot_18"
    }, 
    {
        "playerId" : 62,
        "initialBalance" : "2000.00",
        "seatId" : 1,
        "name" : "Bot_61"
    }, 
    {
        "playerId" : 92,
        "initialBalance" : "2000.00",
        "seatId" : 2,
        "name" : "Bot_91"
    }, 
    {
        "playerId" : 8,
        "initialBalance" : "2000.00",
        "seatId" : 3,
        "name" : "Bot_7"
    }, 
    {
        "playerId" : 85,
        "initialBalance" : "2000.00",
        "seatId" : 4,
        "name" : "Bot_84"
    }, 
    {
        "playerId" : 26,
        "initialBalance" : "2000.00",
        "seatId" : 5,
        "name" : "Bot_25"
    }, 
    {
        "playerId" : 71,
        "initialBalance" : "2000.00",
        "seatId" : 6,
        "name" : "Bot_70"
    }, 
    {
        "playerId" : 82,
        "initialBalance" : "2000.00",
        "seatId" : 7,
        "name" : "Bot_81"
    }.
],
"settings" : {
    "variant" : "TELESINA",
    "currencyCode" : "EUR",
    "betStrategyType" : "NO_LIMIT"
}
}
```

How can I count entries from example player with id 85 ("playerId" : 85), so I can count all this player hands from history and get a total hands that I can use in my bonus system?

in mysqli I would have done like this:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con, "select count(*) as total from handhistoric where playerid='85'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
$total=$row["total"];
```

Then would have the total hands played from user 85 in the variable $total

I have found this, but the result of playerID 85 is int(0)

```
<?php
$connection = new MongoClient("mongodb://ip");
echo "connected<br>";
$collection = $connection->poker->HistoricHand;
echo "colection selected<br>";
$cursor = $collection->find(array("playerId"=>"85"));
var_dump($cursor->count()); //return the total count of documents with "playerId" equal to "85"
```

Result is:
connected
colection selected
int(0)

Comment: I didn't understand your completely might be because of the lengthy document. But, what I could sense is you are trying to fetch some results from a particular playerId and then do some necessary aggregations. If this is the case, you will have to use $unwind to split the results array and do necessary aggregations. Here is the link. https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: Actually what I need is just to count the appearance of the playerid in all documents so that I can determine how many hands a player have played, so we can give a player a bonus then example 50 hands is played